# Solr index only the home page

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-9.x

I have configured solr on my Typo3 web site successfully, The indexing works fine for news.

But for Pages it index only 1 page : Home page.

When Checking the Solr logging i found this error :

```
No stored data found for /schema/analysis/synonyms/english
```

My config :

```
Solr EXT: solr : 9.0.2

Solr Apache : 7.6.0

TYPO3 : 9.5.3

RealUrl enable

http
```

Comment: When checking the T3 report i found this error : `Indexing is disabled
You need to set config.index_enable = 1 to allow page indexing. ` But when I check the root template on my website i already added : `page.config.index_enable = 1` .. Strange !